# How to make a copy of the list?

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def mutate(self, index):
    ing1, ing2 = random.randrange(8), random.randrange(8)
    while ing1 == ing2:
        ing2 = random.randrange(8)
    ptr = self.drinkList[index].ing[:]
    ing1thr = ptr[ing1].max - ptr[ing1].perc
    ing2thr = ptr[ing2].perc - ptr[ing2].min
    mutatedFitness = 0
    if ing1thr & ing2thr:
        change = random.randrange(ing1thr if ing1thr < ing2thr else ing2thr)
        ptr[ing1].perc += change
        ptr[ing2].perc -= change
    for x in ptr:
        mutatedFitness += x.perc * x.price
    mutatedFitness = 280000 - mutatedFitness
    if mutatedFitness > self.drinkList[index].fitness:
        self.drinkList[index].ing = ptr[:]
```

Now, I want the ptr to be a copy of self.drinkList[index].ing list, but in the debugger I noticed it points to the object itself instead of making a copy. I thought slicing was the way to avoid it, where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Slicing should do it, so I see nothing wrong with your code. Trying printing out `id(ptr)` and `id(self.drinkList[index].ing)` -- are you seeing two different values?

Comment: Ok, I solved it using copy.deepcopy(). The nested list still pointed to the same objects.

Comment: What is "ptr" supposed to mean here? Or "thr"? Or "perc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what skrat said

```
import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing creates a `view` object afaik. Use `copy` module.